# Variable or condition declaration after cursor or handler declaration SQL Statement (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, cursor, mysql-workbench

even though i tried many things it still gives me this error (Variable or condition declaration after cursor or handler declaration
SQL Statement)

the sp must use cursors

```
CREATE PROCEDURE monthly_sum (IN cardId INT(36), IN monthN INT, OUT sumV float)
BEGIN
DECLARE cursor_1 CURSOR FOR
SELECT SUM(purchased.amountPurchased)
FROM purchased
WHERE MONTH(purchased.dateUsed) = monthN AND purchased.purchasedCardId = cardId AND DAY(purchased.dateUsed) <=10;

DECLARE cursor_2 CURSOR FOR
SELECT SUM(purchased.amountPurchased)
FROM purchased
WHERE MONTH(purchased.dateUsed)  = monthN AND purchased.purchasedCardId = cardId AND DAY(purchased.dateUsed) <=20 AND DAY(purchased.dateUsed) >10;

DECLARE cursor_3 CURSOR FOR
SELECT SUM(purchased.amountPurchased)
FROM purchased
WHERE MONTH(purchased.dateUsed) = monthN AND purchased.purchasedCardId = cardId AND DAY(purchased.dateUsed) >20;

DECLARE percentage1, percentage2, percentage3 float default 0;

OPEN cursor_1;
FETCH cursor_1
INTO percentage1;
CLOSE cursor_1;

OPEN cursor_2;
FETCH cursor_2
INTO percentage2;
CLOSE cursor_2;

OPEN cursor_3;
FETCH cursor_3
INTO percentage3;
CLOSE cursor_3;
SET sumV = percentage1*0.01 + percentage2*0.02 + percentage1*0.03;

SELECT sumV;
END
```

expected output the sum of 1% of first 10 days, 2% next 10 days, 3% the rest days of the month

Comment: Do you have a reset for the MySQL default delimiter.. like `DELIMITER //`

Comment: Try adding this at the beginning: DECLARE percentage1, percentage2, percentage3 float default 0;

Answer (score 1):

i added DECLARE percentage1, percentage2, percentage3 float default 0; at the beginning like karmens89 comment me and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling cursor unnecessarily you can use `select into`. Since cursor is used to fetch row by row but in your case it results only once.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE monthly_sum (IN cardId INT(36), IN monthN INT, OUT sumV float)
BEGIN

DECLARE percentage1, percentage2, percentage3 float default 0;

SELECT SUM(purchased.amountPurchased) INTO percentage1
FROM purchased
WHERE MONTH(purchased.dateUsed) = monthN 
AND purchased.purchasedCardId = cardId 
AND DAY(purchased.dateUsed) <=10;

SELECT SUM(purchased.amountPurchased) INTO percentage2
FROM purchased
WHERE MONTH(purchased.dateUsed)  = monthN 
AND purchased.purchasedCardId = cardId 
AND DAY(purchased.dateUsed) <=20 AND DAY(purchased.dateUsed) >10;

SELECT SUM(purchased.amountPurchased) INTO percentage3
FROM purchased
WHERE MONTH(purchased.dateUsed) = monthN 
AND purchased.purchasedCardId = cardId 
AND DAY(purchased.dateUsed) >20;

SET sumV = percentage1*0.01 + percentage2*0.02 + percentage1*0.03; # I think percentage3 to be added instead of percentage1
END
```